# Can you recommend a reporting framework/SDK for offline use in a bespoke mobile app

Tags: reporting, mobile, business-intelligence

I have a customer that wants to give metrics and business intelligence capabilities to their sales reps on the road by providing them with iPad app that has their sales data/reports available offline. Loose requirements are:

1. Ability to fetch and store tabular data from a remote server to local device
2. Ability to render data based on some predefined view/configuration
3. Ability to filter/query that database on the device

I know there are lots of tools out their that do this. **PowerBI** looks very slick. **Roambi** & **Tableau** already support the offline capability. What is apparently missing is the ability to integrate these frameworks into your own development/application.